# Matching and Sorting Two Columns for Bank Reconciliation

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I need help for the preparation of Bank Reconciliation Report. Say, I have two sheets, one sheet will contain an ID code for the current month and the other sheet will contain the ID Code for the previous month. It will look like this:

Col. A (Sheet 1)       | Col B (Sheet 2)

```
 A                 |         D
 B                 |         C
 C                 |         E
 D                 |         B
 E                 |         A
 F
```

I want a macro that will automatically sort and match the two columns ending up with something like this:

Col. A (Sheet 1)       | Col B (Sheet 2)

```
 A                 |         A
 B                 |         B
 C                 |         C
 D                 |         D
 E                 |         E
```

Take note that the **F** in column A (sheet 1) was deleted because it has no match in col. B. 
Please help me with this, I am new when it comes to excel vba.

Comment: Will there only ever be one record per month? For example, on Sheet1 will there only ever be one "A" and only one corresponding "A" on Sheet2?

Comment: @Remnant - apparently there is a possibility that there will be two "A"'s.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a macro, which is probably cleaner. Use the `countif()` function to determine the matches from one column to the other, then delete rows if `countif()` is zero, now you can just use `vlookup()` and you're there.

Hope this helps.